# surjectivity and injectivity of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following question here.

> A certain linear transformation $\varphi:P_3 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$
> maps the polynomial $x^3+3x^2+5x+7$ to  $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\\
> \end{pmatrix}$ and $x^3+2x^2+3x+4$ to $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\\\end{pmatrix}$. What can we conclude aboout $\varphi$?
>
> a) It is injective and surjective.
>
> b) It is injective but not surjective.
>
> c) It is surjective but not injective.
>
> d) It is neither injective nor surjective.
>
> e) It is impossible to decide whether it is surjective, but we know it is not injective.

I'm tempted to say neither. For the transformation to be surjective, $\ker(\varphi)$ must be the zero polynomial but I can't really say that's the case here. I can't even conclude if the transformation is $1-1$ so I don't think it's injective.

For surjectivity, the codomain of the linear transformation (The image) has to describe all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but I don't think I can really conclude this either.

So as such, my answer choice is D but I don't think this is right.

Can someone offer some guidance?

**EDIT:** I changed $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The images of the two polynomials are not in $\mathbb R^{3}$.

Comment: Sorry. I just corrected my question @KaviRamaMurthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think you mean in your first paragraph that for the transformation to be *injective*, $\operatorname{ker} \varphi$ must be the zero polynomial. This is a true statement, so the fact that $\varphi$ maps $x^3+3x^2+5x+7$ to $(0,0)$ tells us that $\varphi$ is not injective.

Secondly, for surjectivity, the image of the linear transformation has to be all of $\mathbb R^2$. The only information we have here is that $\varphi$ maps $x^3+2x^2+3x+4$ to $(1,0)$, so your reasoning is correct that we can't necessarily conclude that $\varphi$ is surjective.

Now can you conclude?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I absolutely did mean to say that first bit.

This might seem like a silly question but how do you know that given $\varphi$ maps $x^3+3x^2+5x+7$ to $(0,0)$ tells us that $\varphi$ is not injective? How does that imply we do not get the $0$ polynomial?

Comment: A linear transformation is injective if and only if it has trivial kernel. That is, the zero vector in the domain is the only element that maps to the zero vector in the codomain. In this case, the vector $x^3+3x^2+5x+7$ is mapped to the zero vector in the codomain, and so we have a nontrivial kernel. Therefore, $\varphi$ is not injective.

Comment: Okay so I might be really digging deep here but why is this true? "In this case, the vector $x^3+3x^2+5x+7$ is mapped to the zero vector in the codomain, and so we have a nontrivial kernel."

If you get the $0$ vector in the codomain, why would that give you any information about the kernel?

Comment: The kernel is *defined* as the set of all elements that are mapped to the zero vector.

Comment: I agree! But then if the given transformation maps the first vector to $0$, doesn't that mean that $\varphi$ IS injective? Since $\varphi$ maps the first vector to $0$.

In fact I think because $\varphi$ does not map the second vector to $0$, THAT is the reason why it's not injective. Why is this reasoning incorrect?

Comment: Perhaps think about this fact: $\varphi$ maps the zero polynomial to $(0,0).$ (all linear transformations map the zero vector to the zero vector). However, from the above, it *also* maps $x^3+3x^2+5x+7$ to the zero vector. So it is not one-to-one! ie. not injective.

Comment: That made sense! Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries! Anytime.